Choosing products in categories appearing in practice
Is there any category $\mathcal{C}$  appearing in practice* which has binary products but it is not possible to choose them in a canonical way? By dualization, what about binary coproducts?
A bit more formal, it is required that $\mathsf{ZF}$ (plus universes) proves that every pair of objects in $\mathcal{C}$ has a binary product, but $\mathsf{ZF}$ does not prove that a functor $\times : \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ exists which makes a choice of binary products.
It is well-known that the axiom of choice or a different definition of a functor is necessary to construct such a functor in general. But in practice I have never seen any example where it was actually necessary, hence my question. We can construct products and coproducts of groups, rings, spaces, generalized metric spaces, sheaves, manifolds, etc. in a canonical way. The usual ad-hoc gluing construction of products of schemes is a bit problematic, but it can be replaced by this one that works for all locally ringed spaces and provides a functor.
Equivalently, is there any disadvantage when defining a category with binary products as one with chosen binary products? Is there any category where this definition is not adequate? I can't think of any disadvantage. Quite the opposite, functor categories and monads will be better behaved.
Of course the same questions apply to all sorts of limits and colimits, but to keep it simple I want to restrict to binary products here. Feel free to include infinite products if it makes a difference.
*For this question I am not interested in artificial counterexamples, only in categories that are already studied or are slight variations. The question arises in the context of preparing teaching material for basic category theory, which also means that elementary examples are very much appreciated. Of course the proof that AC is actually required will not be elementary, but that's OK. I am also not interested in homotopical or higher categorical versions here, just ordinary categories.
Here is an artificial counterexample, not relevant for practice, hence offtopic: objects are rings, morphisms are maps of the underlying sets. This has binary coproducts, since the disjoint union of the underlying sets has some ring structure, but there is no canonical choice.
Here is an example where you can choose binary coproducts in a (sort of) canonical way, but it is not immediately obvious. Consider the category of metric spaces with continuous maps. It is canonically equivalent to its subcategory of metric spaces whose metric is $ < 1$ (take $d_b(x,x') := d(x,x') / (1 + d(x,x'))$ as usual). If $(X,d_X)$, $(Y,d_Y)$ are two metric spaces where $d_X,d_Y < 1$, we define a metric $d_{X \sqcup Y}$ on $X \sqcup Y$ by using the existing metrics as well as $d_{X \sqcup Y}(x,y) := 1$ and $d_{X \times Y}(y,x) := 1$ for $x \in X$, $y \in Y$ (see here). This is a coproduct. (When we allow $\infty$ as a value of our metrics, this detour via bounded metrics is not necessary.)

Would the category of finite subsets of a given $X$ (and set maps between them) work for you? You can get canonical choices of products if $X$ is totally ordered, but if $X$ is infinite and does not come with an order, you may need choice to put it all together... I ask because I can easily see this being called "artificial".

That's a weird category (the objects have stuff that is ignored by the morphisms) which also doesn't have products. Perhaps you meant different morphisms?

Fair enough, that's why  I asked. But why doesn't it have (binary) products? If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of size $n$ and $m$, then any subset of size $nm$ will function as a product with suitable projections. I'm thinking of $X$ infinite, of course. Is the "stuff that is ignored by the morphisms" the fact that they are subsets of a given $X$?

Oups I overlooked that your X is infinite. Then binary products exist. But please ask yourself if this category ever appears in practice. Indeed the definition of the objects is off. I will even argue that morally this should not be regarded as a category with products (i.e. the second definition makes more sense here).

It is somewhat similar to the category of rings with morphisms being the maps of the underlying sets. It has binary coproducts, but no canonical ones. This is the kind of artificial (and useless) examples, where objects and morphisms are not connected at all, that I would like to exclude, and that probably nobody will miss either way when we talk about (co-)products in categories. Let me add this to the post.

I think in practice people are secretly thinking of the strong definition (i.e. with a choice of product) when they say “category with products” and justifying to themselves with the argument you give. Certainly that was what I was thinking to myself when I wrote my thesis…

@MartinBrandenburg Category of underlying sets of rings is not only equivalent, but even isomorphic (non-canonically) to the category of sets. If your definition (whatever it is) of artificial and useless does not transfer via isomorphism of categories, one may start to have doubts about usefulness of such definition.

I don't agree. In ZF the category of rings with underlying set maps isn't isomorphic to the category of nonempty sets. You won't be able to write down an inverse functor. The notion of "artificial" will be invariant under isomorphisms and in fact equivalences of categories that exist in ZF. Also notice that the property of having chosen products (including chosen projections) is invariant under equivalences. Here, equivalences of categories are not just essentially surjective fully faithful functors, in ZF that's not enough. We need a pseudo-inverse functor as in their definition. @xsnl

Regardless of the question if the notion of artificial should be invariant under equivalences in ZFC in general, my question here belongs to ZF, so this is the system we should focus on. @xsnl

It's not clear to me whether the category of metric spaces and continuous maps would satisfy you. On one hand, it's very similar to your artificial example of rings/functions, in that the objects have extra structure that the morphisms ignore. On the other hand, it seems a more "in practice" example, as typically people would learn about metric spaces and continuous maps between them before they learn about topological spaces. I've not checked carefully that one can't choose a coproduct of metric spaces without choice, but I'd be slightly surprised if one could.

@JeremyRickard Oh yes, this seems to be a good example. I am not particularly happy that there are examples ;) since it means my implicit proposal is wrong, but it is what it is. I will accept it as an answer!

OK, I'll think it through more carefully, and post an answer if it seems to hold up.

@JeremyRickard Why shouldn't it hold up?

@MartinBrandenburg I've not had time yet to think very hard about it, and maybe there's an obvious argument, but what I'm missing is a proof that in ZF there is no canonical way to choose binary coproducts. Is the corresponding fact for rings/functions obvious?

@JeremyRickard Oups. Actually that category has (sort of) canonical coproducts as well. See my recent edit.

@MartinBrandenburg Nice argument. Are you 100% sure there is nothing similar for rings/functions? It seems unlikely ... but that's what I thought about metric spaces.
